# How to Transfer Test case or Projects properties in to scriopt assertion?

Tags: groovy, properties, soapui

I am new to Groovy Script and SOAPUI. I have a scenario like this.
I get a list of objects and inside object Array of values will be there. I need to get one of the value in the in side Object and In side Array and need to be assert with Test case or Project Property.

So, please let me know how to get the Property value in to Script assertion and how to loop those objects and arrays in my JSON Response and how do I compare with my Property?
Following is the snippet from `Script Assertion`

```
def testSuiteProperty = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "IPADDRESS" )
log.info context.expand( '${testSuite#IPADDRESS}' )
```

Getting below error:

> No such property: testRunner for class Script42.

Please give me code for Getting the value from Project or Test case or Test suite and i need to put that value in to `Script Assertion`?

Comment: Please give more context and show us what you have already tried to get done.

Comment: def testSuiteProperty  = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "IPADDRESS" )
log.info context.expand( '${testSuite#IPADDRESS}' )

Comment: I am getting error like this when i execute that Script Assertion

Comment: No such property: testRunner for class Script42.Please give me code for Getting the value from Project or Test case or Test suite and i need to put that value in to Script Assertion?

Comment: @SaikiranGarapati, you can check the answer and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, here is the error in your code snippet.

`testSuite` is not a valid reference. It should be `TestSuite`.

[This](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html) documentation link should help for better understanding.

Also `testRunner` is not valid object within Script Assertion scope. And only

`context, log, and messageExchange` are valid objects in `Script Assertion` which you can see in below image.

[image]

Instead, use below code to be able access the value that you are looking for:

```
def testSuiteProperty = context.expand('${#TestSuite#IPADDRESS}') 
//Alternatively you may also use below statement which works same as above one.
//def testSuiteProperty = context.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue('IPADDRESS') 
log.info testSuiteProperty
```